# How to pass iterator to method as parameter and how it works ?? any example in java

Tags: java, iterator

How to pass iterator to method as parameter and how it works ?? any example .
where callee would look like this :

```
void someMethod(Iterator<String> data) {     

}
```

how we can use this "data" object ... Any example

need example to understand how iterator works when passed as parameter to a method.

Comment: What makes you think using it, or how it works, is any different when passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Iterator exactly as you wrote

```
private static void method(Iterator<String> iterator) {
    iterator.hasNext();

    iterator.next();

    iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

}
```

You can check if there is next element with hasNext(), you can take next element with next(). Or you can iterate throught elements what left in collection.

for example if you create list with 5 elements and then invoke next() two times

forEachRemaining() will use 3 elements what left.

forEachRemaining accept Consumer so this is something like bellow

```
System.out::prinln
```

or equivalent

```
x -> System.out.println(x)
```

Consume is an instruction how to use an argument

As example of usage you can use iterator to go throught csv file.
You can read first line as header and then parse rest lines into objects